# Is it possible to disable the 5 second time limit for Azure CosmosDB stored procedures

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have recently been doing some work using a stored procedure in Azure's CosmosDB to update some documents. The Documents are a bit chunky (5000+ lines documents and dealing with about a 1000 of them) and the sproc takes more than 5 seconds to run. The 5 second limit stops the sproc from running, throwing the time limit exceeded error. So, I am asking if this can be turned off or configured?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656072/what-happens-when-5-second-execution-time-limit-exceeds-in-azure-documentdb-stor) about some possible work arounds, which I am looking at along with some other ideas, but, to be clear, the purpose of this question is to establish if this 5 second limit can be turned off or configured not if I can work around it.

I have been trying to find somewhere in the official docs that says this, so if anyone knows where that is that would be great.

I have also tried increasing the throughput on the collection to reduce the time it takes to run. This helps, but the sproc still hits the limit.

Comment: This isn't configurable. The only thing you can change, aside from RU provisioning, is your data model. Or potentially your stored procedure, to find optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I don't suppose you know if that is going to change at any point?

Comment: I don't, but that's not something that would be discussable anyway (roadmap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, I am asking if this can be turned off or configured?

Clearly, as @David Makogon said the limitation of cosmos db stored procedure runtime can't be turned off or configured.

So , I recommand you adopt workaround in the thread :[What happens when 5 second execution time limit exceeds in Azure DocumentDb Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656072/what-happens-when-5-second-execution-time-limit-exceeds-in-azure-documentdb-stor). Please use [continuation tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/common-documentdb-rest-response-headers) to process data in batchs. You could refer to the `pseudo-code` as below :

```
function updateArticlesDetailsX() {

       var collection = getContext().getCollection();
       var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
       var response = getContext().getResponse();
       var docCount = 0;
       var counter = 0;

       tryQueryAndUpdate();

       function tryQueryAndUpdate(continuation) {
            var query = {
                query: "select * from root r"
            };

            var requestOptions = {
                continuation: continuation
            };

            var isAccepted =
                collection
                .queryDocuments(collectionLink,
                                query,
                                requestOptions,
                                function queryCallback(err, documents, responseOptions) {
                                         if (err) throw err;
                                         if (documents.length > 0) {
                                            // If at least one document is found, update it.
                                            docCount = documents.length;
                                            for (var i=0; i<docCount; i++){
                                                tryUpdate(documents[i]);
                                            }
                                            response.setBody("Updated " + docCount + " documents");
                                          }
                                          else if (responseOptions.continuation) {
                                              // Else if the query came back empty, but with a continuation token; 
                                              // repeat the query w/ the token.
                                            tryQueryAndUpdate(responseOptions.continuation);
                                          } else {
                                                 throw new Error("Document not found.");
                                                 }
                                });

            if (!isAccepted) {
                throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out");
            }
        }

        function tryUpdate(document) {
            //Optimistic concurrency control via HTTP ETag.
            var requestOptions = { etag: document._etag };

            //Update statement goes here:
            document.x = "some new value";

            var isAccepted = collection
                             .replaceDocument(document._self,
                                              document,
                                              requestOptions,
                                              function replaceCallback(err, updatedDocument, responseOptions) {
                                                       if (err) throw err;
                                                       counter++;
                                               });

            // If we hit execution bounds - throw an exception.
            if (!isAccepted) {
                throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out");
            }
        }
    }
```

In addition, if your document is too large so that you could just handle only a few per batch (usually not, because the size of document has a `2M` limit) , maybe you should optimize your data structure to make your document snappy.

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks for response. As I said in the OP I am looking at some alternatives and will look at your example here. I was after a definitive yes or no, which I got :)