# CosmosDB stored procedure not returning all documents

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

i have a pretty simple stored procedure that returns 0 to many documents.  Here is the code:

```
function GetAllDocuments(numberOfDays){

  var context = getContext();
  var response = context.getResponse();
  var collection = context.getCollection();
  var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

  var today  = new Date();  
  today.setDate(today.getDate() - numberOfDays);
  var inSeconds = today.getTime() / 1000; 
  var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts >' + inSeconds;

  console.log(filterQuery);
  collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, {pageSize:-1},
    function(err, documents) {
      response.setBody(response.getBody() + JSON.stringify(documents));
    }
  );
}
```

The issue I am facing is, if there are many documents to be returned ie 20000 not all documents are returned.  I think i am running into the issue where i need to pass a continuationToken.  I have read other posts that states that we will need to return to client(c#) then make another call to the sproc passing in a token.  I havent been able to find a code sample.  Also is that the only way to ensure full return?  Is it just a stored procedure issue?  Will i be better off to just use client.CreateDocumentQuery that will simply return all records in one call?

Thanks for any feedback!

This is the new code using Jay's sample:

```
function GetAllDocumentsNew(numberOfDays) {

       var collection = getContext().getCollection();
       var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
       var response = getContext().getResponse();
       var docCount = 0;
       var counter = 0;
       var returnArray = [];

       var today  = new Date();  
       today.setDate(today.getDate() - numberOfDays);
       var inSeconds = today.getTime() / 1000; 
       //var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts >' + inSeconds;
       var filterQuery = "select * from c where c._ts > 1531763849.225 and c._ts <1532637743.261 and c.ProcessTypeID = 1";

       console.log(filterQuery);

       tryQuery();

       function tryQuery(continuation) {
            var query = {
                query: filterQuery
            };

            var requestOptions = {
                MaxItemCount: 10000,
                continuation: continuation
            };

            var isAccepted =
                collection
                .queryDocuments(collectionLink,
                                query,
                                requestOptions,
                                function queryCallback(err, documents,responseOptions) {
                                         if (err) throw err;
                                         if (documents.length > 0) {

                                            docCount = documents.length;
                                            console.log(docCount.toString());
                                            for (var i=0; i<docCount; i++){
                                                returnArray.push(documents[i]);
                                            }

                                           getContext().getResponse().setBody(returnArray);
                                          }
                                          else if (responseOptions.continuation) {
                                              // Else if the query came back empty, but with a continuation token; 
                                              // repeat the query with the token.
                                            tryQuery(responseOptions.continuation);
                                          } else {
                                                 throw new Error("Document not found.");
                                                 }
                                });

            if (!isAccepted) {
                throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `client.CreateDocumentQuery` will still make the same amount of calls

Comment: Yeah based on my experiment I think what it is doing is one fetch per document.  I actually have it running now and it is painfully slow.  Have been mucking around with this 2 days now, still hoping there is a simpler way.

Comment: I made this little library called [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) that might solve your problem. Just create a `CosmosStore` for your object and do a `await cosmosStore.Query().ToListAsync()` or `QueryMultipleAsync("sql")` if you wanna use SQL and see if you get everything back.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

> if there are many documents to be returned ie 20000 not all documents
>   are returned. I think i am running into the issue where i need to pass
>   a continuationToken.

When the query data is quite huge,of course, you need to consider use continuation token in stored procedure. You could refer to the pseudo-code as below:

```
function GetAllDocuments(numberOfDays) {

       var collection = getContext().getCollection();
       var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
       var response = getContext().getResponse();
       var docCount = 0;
       var counter = 0;
       var returnArray = [];

       var today  = new Date();  
       today.setDate(today.getDate() - numberOfDays);
       var inSeconds = today.getTime() / 1000; 
       var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts >' + inSeconds;

       tryQuery();

       function tryQuery(continuation) {
            var query = {
                query: "select * from root r"
            };

            var requestOptions = {
                MaxItemCount: 1000
                continuation: continuation
            };

            var isAccepted =
                collection
                .queryDocuments(collectionLink,
                                query,
                                requestOptions,
                                function queryCallback(err, documents,responseOptions) {
                                         if (err) throw err;
                                         if (documents.length > 0) {

                                            docCount = documents.length;
                                            for (var i=0; i<docCount; i++){
                                                returnArray.push(documents[i]);
                                            }

                                           getContext().getResponse().setBody(returnArray);
                                          }
                                          else if (responseOptions.continuation) {
                                              // Else if the query came back empty, but with a continuation token; 
                                              // repeat the query with the token.
                                            tryQuery(responseOptions.continuation);
                                          } else {
                                                 throw new Error("Document not found.");
                                                 }
                                });

            if (!isAccepted) {
                throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out");
            }
        }
    }
```

> I have read other posts that states that we will need to return to
>   client(c#) then make another call to the sproc passing in a token. I
>   havent been able to find a code sample.

As I know, stored procedure has `5` seconds running limitation([Is it possible to disable the 5 second time limit for Azure CosmosDB stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158257/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-5-second-time-limit-for-azure-cosmosdb-stored-proc/49164454#49164454).So), if your stored procedure time out,you need to call `[ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync][1]` on your client side and pass the continuation token as parameter.

> Will i be better off to just use client.CreateDocumentQuery that will
>   simply return all records in one call?

Per my knowledge,stored procedures are JS code scripts which running on the server side.I presume that performance is more efficient than using client invoke SDK. However, it is limited to the JS syntax and running time.If you can not tolerate these features,i suggest you could complete your requirements via client SDK.

Hope it helps you.Any concern ,please let me know.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for your post.  It is very helpful!  I went ahead and tried your sample code with some minor changes, i am still not getting all the documents back.  I am a newbie in cosmos stored procedure so it's highly possible i am doing something wrong...

Comment: @wysiwyg Never mind,I will help you get through.Have you use console.log() to trace the error? Or did you get any error details?

Comment: Hi Jay, there wasnt any error, i just know that it did not return all the documents.  Let me know what other info you need.  Thanks Jay.

Comment: @wysiwyg Could you share your present stored procedure function code?How did you use continuation token?

Comment: updated the original post.  I didnt make much change at all except i updated the query variable to = filterQuery.  Thanks again Jay.